SwiftData FatalError Unknown Relationship Key
Some of our users on iOS 17.5+ started to encounter crash due to:
SwiftData/BackingData.swift:669: Fatal error: Unknown Relationship Key - subscription)
We started using SwiftData only on the MainActor but this issue still exists. It doesn't affect all of our users but some of them still encounter this crash. Apple Documentation doesn't really say what should be done in this case and forums contain only examples with arrays.

Our models look like these:
@Model
public final class ProfileModel {

    public static let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<ProfileModel>.self

    public enum Gender: Codable {
        case female
        case male
        case other
    }

    public enum Units: Codable {
        case imperial
        case metric
    }

    public enum Eating: Codable {
        case empath
        case enthusiast
        case explorer
        case guardian
        case harmonizer
        case pacifier
        case regulator
        case stoic
        case iosDefault
    }

    public enum RegistrationSource: Codable {
        case iOS
        case web
    }

    public enum NHE: Codable {
        case combined
        case emotional
        case mindless
    }

    public enum Goal: Codable {
        case beHealthier
        case energyIncrease
        case healthyHabits
        case looseWeight
        case relationshipsWithFood
    }

    public enum WeightLossFocus: Codable {
        case activity
        case healthyHabits
        case nutrition
        case other
    }

    @Attribute(.unique)
    public let id: String

    public let isPaid: Bool
    public let eating: Eating
    public let registrationSource: RegistrationSource
    public let nhe: NHE?
    public let firstName: String?
    public let lastName: String?
    public let gender: Gender?
    public let height: String?
    public let age: Int?
    public let weight: String?
    public let targetWeight: String?
    public let bmi: String?
    public let goal: Goal?
    public let units: Units?
    public let weightLossFocus: WeightLossFocus?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    public var subscription: ProfileSubscriptionModel?

    public init(
        id: String,
        isPaid: Bool,
        eating: Eating,
        registrationSource: RegistrationSource,
        nhe: NHE?,
        firstName: String?,
        lastName: String?,
        gender: Gender?,
        height: String?,
        age: Int?,
        weight: String?,
        targetWeight: String?,
        bmi: String?,
        goal: Goal?,
        units: Units?,
        weightLossFocus: WeightLossFocus?,
        subscription: ProfileSubscriptionModel?
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.isPaid = isPaid
        self.eating = eating
        self.registrationSource = registrationSource
        self.nhe = nhe
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.gender = gender
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.targetWeight = targetWeight
        self.bmi = bmi
        self.goal = goal
        self.units = units
        self.weightLossFocus = weightLossFocus
        self.subscription = subscription
    }
}

@Model
public final class ProfileSubscriptionModel {

    public static let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<ProfileSubscriptionModel>.self

    public let price: Double
    public let currency: String
    public let period: Int
    public let status: String
    public let expirationDate: Date
    public let cancelledAt: Date?

    public init(price: Double, currency: String, period: Int, status: String, expirationDate: Date, cancelledAt: Date?) {
        self.price = price
        self.currency = currency
        self.period = period
        self.status = status
        self.expirationDate = expirationDate
        self.cancelledAt = cancelledAt
    }
}


Here is a stack trace:
Crashed: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x3033927d0

Crashed: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x3033927d0
0   libswiftCore.dylib             0x398c0 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 264
1   SwiftData                      0x9c79c __swift_memcpy9_8 + 11448
2   SwiftData                      0x9ea58 __swift_memcpy9_8 + 20340
3   SwiftData                      0xa35ec __swift_memcpy9_8 + 39688
4   SwiftData                      0x54508 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 7180
5   SwiftData                      0x55d0c __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 13328
6   SwiftData                      0x5340c __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 2832
7   SwiftData                      0x532d0 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 2516
8   Mindea                         0x2da9c closure #1 in ProfileModel.subscription.setter + 13 (@__swiftmacro_13StorageBoxAPI12ProfileModelC12subscription18_PersistedPropertyfMa_.swift:13)
9   Mindea                         0x32578 partial apply for closure #1 in ProfileModel.subscription.setter + 4333757816 (<compiler-generated>:4333757816)
10  Mindea                         0x35fd0 closure #1 in ProfileModel.subscription.setterpartial apply + 4333772752
11  libswiftObservation.dylib      0x6e9c ObservationRegistrar.withMutation<A, B, C>(of:keyPath:_:) + 100
12  Mindea                         0x32f50 specialized ProfileModel.init(id:isPaid:eating:registrationSource:nhe:firstName:lastName:gender:height:age:weight:targetWeight:bmi:goal:units:weightLossFocus:subscription:) + 12 (@__swiftmacro_13StorageBoxAPI12ProfileModelC12subscription18_PersistedPropertyfMa_.swift:12)
13  Mindea                         0x2df50 ProfileModel.init(id:isPaid:eating:registrationSource:nhe:firstName:lastName:gender:height:age:weight:targetWeight:bmi:goal:units:weightLossFocus:subscription:) + 4333739856 (<compiler-generated>:4333739856)
14  Mindea                         0x5200c specialized ProfileModel.init(_:) + 9 (@__swiftmacro_10StorageBox13ModelSchemeV1O011UserProfileC0C15weightLossFocus18_PersistedPropertyfMa_.swift:9)
15  Mindea                         0x3df68 closure #1 in variable initialization expression of static MigrationPlan.migrateV1toV2 + 26 (MigrationPlan.swift:26)
16  SwiftData                      0x4d63c __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0Tm + 114548
17  SwiftData                      0x4d584 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0Tm + 114364
18  SwiftData                      0x89c4 _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 6980
19  SwiftData                      0xe364 objectdestroyTm + 120
20  CoreData                       0x105c3c closure #1 in NSCustomMigrationStage.willMigrateHandler.setter + 44
21  CoreData                       0x105ccc partial apply for closure #1 in NSCustomMigrationStage.didMigrateHandler.setter + 20
22  CoreData                       0x10571c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed NSStagedMigrationManager, @guaranteed NSCustomMigrationStage, @unowned AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>?) -> (@unowned Bool) + 88
23  CoreData                       0x186bb0 __70-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator applyMigrationStage:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 116
24  CoreData                       0x1868e8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator createPersistentContainerForMigrationContext:withModel:andExecuteBlock:] + 480
25  CoreData                       0x1862cc -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator applyMigrationStage:withContext:error:] + 1516
26  CoreData                       0x182c50 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator migrateStoreWithContext:error:] + 1040
27  CoreData                       0xc666c __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 3672
28  CoreData                       0x1e87c gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 204
29  libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
30  libdispatch.dylib              0x132c4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
31  CoreData                       0x11cb4 _perform + 176
32  CoreData                       0xc54a8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 424
33  CoreData                       0xdc44c -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _doAddPersistentStoreWithDescription:privateCopy:completeOnMainThread:withHandler:] + 400
34  CoreData                       0xdc1f0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithDescription:completionHandler:] + 228
35  CoreData                       0xdca1c -[NSPersistentContainer _loadStoreDescriptions:withCompletionHandler:] + 184
36  CoreData                       0xdbcc0 -[NSPersistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:] + 248
37  CoreData                       0x224f10 -[NSPersistentContainer(CoreDataSPI) load:] + 240
38  SwiftData                      0xd10c _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 25228
39  SwiftData                      0x78e0 _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 2656
40  SwiftData                      0xe0c8 _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 29256
41  SwiftData                      0x7510 _swift_stdlib_malloc_size + 1680
42  SwiftData                      0xfb20 block_destroy_helper + 4120
43  SwiftData                      0xf178 block_destroy_helper + 1648
44  Mindea                         0x3b9e4 DataBaseManager.init(loggerManager:) + 35 (DataBaseManager.swift:35)
45  Mindea                         0x12608 closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.registerStorageBox() + 14 (DependencyContainer+StorageBox.swift:14)
46  Mindea                         0xadbc specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333596092
47  Mindea                         0x1042c specialized NewDependencyContainer.resolveDependency<A>() + 4333618220
48  Mindea                         0x12680 closure #2 in NewDependencyContainer.registerStorageBox() + 4333627008
49  Mindea                         0xa9d8 specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333595096
50  Mindea                         0x16908 NewDependencyContainer.resolveDependency<A>() + 50 (NewDependencyContainer.swift:50)
51  Mindea                         0x16868 protocol witness for Resolver.resolveDependency<A>() in conformance NewDependencyContainer + 4333643880 (<compiler-generated>:4333643880)
52  Mindea                         0xefdd64 Container.resolveDependency<A>() + 63 (Container.swift:63)
53  Mindea                         0xefe09c protocol witness for Resolver.resolveDependency<A>() in conformance Container + 4349272220 (<compiler-generated>:4349272220)
54  Mindea                         0x8948 closure #1 in DependencyContainer.registerUserSettingsFlowData() + 19 (DependencyContainer+UserSettingsFlowData.swift:19)
55  Mindea                         0xefdb7c closure #1 in Container.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 51 (Container.swift:51)
56  Mindea                         0xefdcc4 Container.resolveDependency<A>() + 60 (Container.swift:60)
57  Mindea                         0xc368 partial apply for closure #1 in AppDelegate.init() + 4333601640
58  Mindea                         0xadbc specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333596092
59  Mindea                         0xc2c4 partial apply for specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333601476 (<compiler-generated>:4333601476)
60  Mindea                         0x1042c specialized NewDependencyContainer.resolveDependency<A>() + 4333618220
61  Mindea                         0x10e04 closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.registerNetworkBox() + 25 (DependencyContainer+NetworkBox.swift:25)
62  Mindea                         0xa9d8 specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333595096
63  Mindea                         0xc1e4 partial apply for specialized closure #1 in NewDependencyContainer.register<A>(scope:factory:) + 4333601252 (<compiler-generated>:4333601252)
64  Mindea                         0x16908 NewDependencyContainer.resolveDependency<A>() + 50 (NewDependencyContainer.swift:50)
65  Mindea                         0x16868 protocol witness for Resolver.resolveDependency<A>() in conformance NewDependencyContainer + 4333643880 (<compiler-generated>:4333643880)
66  Mindea                         0xefdd64 Container.resolveDependency<A>() + 63 (Container.swift:63)
67  Mindea                         0xefe09c protocol witness for Resolver.resolveDependency<A>() in conformance Container + 4349272220 (<compiler-generated>:4349272220)
68  Mindea                         0xeffe6c ViewModelContainer.resolveDependency<A>() + 58 (ViewModelContainer.swift:58)
69  Mindea                         0xefe09c protocol witness for Resolver.resolveDependency<A>() in conformance Container + 4349272220 (<compiler-generated>:4349272220)
70  Mindea                         0x80348 closure #1 in ViewModelContainer.registerAppFlow() + 4334076744 (RemoteProfileUseCaseRepository.swift:4334076744)
71  Mindea                         0xefeb34 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Resolver) -> (@out A) + 4349274932 (<compiler-generated>:4349274932)
72  Mindea                         0xefdcc4 Container.resolveDependency<A>() + 60 (Container.swift:60)
73  Mindea                         0xf00e18 ViewModelFactory.build<A>() + 21 (ViewFactory.swift:21)
74  Mindea                         0x12888 closure #1 in MindeaApp.body.getter + 24 (MindeaApp.swift:24)
75  SwiftUI                        0x427bc0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 626180
76  Mindea                         0x13708 protocol witness for App.body.getter in conformance MindeaApp + 22 (MindeaApp.swift:22)
77  SwiftUI                        0x412a84 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 539848
78  SwiftUI                        0x24d738 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled] + 31980
79  SwiftUI                        0x24b3bc -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled] + 22896
80  SwiftUI                        0x1fdb30 dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 5492
81  AttributeGraph                 0x9010 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 512
82  AttributeGraph                 0x8bfc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 424
83  AttributeGraph                 0x2cc0 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 720
84  AttributeGraph                 0x2854 AGGraphGetValue + 228
85  SwiftUI                        0x1fefd8 dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 10780
86  SwiftUI                        0x1feeec dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 10544
87  SwiftUI                        0x1fea4c dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 9360
88  SwiftUI                        0x1fdb30 dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 5492
89  AttributeGraph                 0x9010 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 512
90  AttributeGraph                 0x8bfc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 424
91  AttributeGraph                 0x2cc0 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 720
92  AttributeGraph                 0x2854 AGGraphGetValue + 228
93  SwiftUI                        0x408d1c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 499552
94  SwiftUI                        0x134ef8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_164 + 43160
95  SwiftUI                        0x1fdb30 dynamic_cast_existential_0_superclass_conditional + 5492
96  AttributeGraph                 0x9010 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 512
97  AttributeGraph                 0x8bfc AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 424
98  AttributeGraph                 0xfef8 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&) + 288
99  AttributeGraph                 0x28a4 AGGraphGetValue + 308
100 SwiftUI                        0x39e768 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 63916
101 SwiftUI                        0x133618 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_164 + 36792
102 SwiftUI                        0x10d350 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_831 + 8884
103 SwiftUI                        0x407078 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 492220
104 UIKitCore                      0x19acc0 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1080
105 UIKitCore                      0x442d28 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 808
106 UIKitCore                      0x2ff94c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 360
107 UIKitCore                      0x2ff600 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
108 FrontBoardServices             0x1a974 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 324
109 FrontBoardServices             0x1a808 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108 + 280
110 FrontBoardServices             0x166cc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
111 FrontBoardServices             0x1acc4 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352
112 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
113 libdispatch.dylib              0x786c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 288
114 FrontBoardServices             0x17d58 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
115 FrontBoardServices             0x17cd8 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
116 FrontBoardServices             0x17bb0 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
117 CoreFoundation                 0x56834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
118 CoreFoundation                 0x567c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
119 CoreFoundation                 0x542f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
120 CoreFoundation                 0x53484 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
121 CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
122 GraphicsServices               0x11a8 GSEventRunModal + 164
123 UIKitCore                      0x40a90c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
124 UIKitCore                      0x4be9d0 UIApplicationMain + 340
125 SwiftUI                        0x3f4148 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 414604
126 SwiftUI                        0x3a0714 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 72024
127 SwiftUI                        0x3ac4d0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283 + 120596
128 Mindea                         0x13860 main + 4333631584 (MindeaApp.swift:4333631584)
129 ???                            0x1b4249e4c (Missing)

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10c4 start_wqthread + 8281768130

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x5008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4d60 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x53f5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x53600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  Foundation                     0xc7e4c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8  Foundation                     0xc7c9c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9  UIKitCore                      0x41e640 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420
10 Foundation                     0xde718 __NSThread__start__ + 732
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x606c _pthread_start + 136
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10d8 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

com.google.fira.worker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7d0c __ulock_wait + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x47c4 _dlock_wait + 56
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x4578 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x135b0 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 368
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1315c _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 148
5  Mindea                         0x146f488 -[APMIdentity identifierForVendor] + 4354978952
6  Mindea                         0x1485af0 APMUpdateConsentSignalsAndIdentifiers + 4355070704
7  Mindea                         0x148b634 -[APMMeasurement(Event) createRawEventMetadataWithUserAttributes:] + 4355094068
8  Mindea                         0x148d334 -[APMMeasurement(Event) writeEvent:isPublicEvent:isRealtime:] + 4355101492
9  Mindea                         0x148b0e8 __57-[APMMeasurement(Event) writeFilteredEventOnWorkerQueue:]_block_invoke + 4355092712
10 Mindea                         0x14da0d4 -[APMSqliteStore performTransactionWithError:block:] + 4355416276
11 Mindea                         0x1451e7c -[APMDatabase performTransaction:] + 4354858620
12 Mindea                         0x148ae3c -[APMMeasurement(Event) writeFilteredEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4355092028
13 Mindea                         0x148aba4 -[APMMeasurement(Event) writeEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4355091364
14 Mindea                         0x148a77c -[APMMeasurement(Event) handleEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4355090300
15 Mindea                         0x148a490 -[APMMeasurement(Event) handleInternalEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4355089552
16 Mindea                         0x147ad58 -[APMMeasurement reportSessionStartOnWorkerQueueWithTimestamp:appInBackground:] + 4355026264
17 Mindea                         0x147b1e4 -[APMMeasurement reportFirstOpenOnWorkerQueue] + 4355027428
18 Mindea                         0x147a6d0 __47-[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke + 4355024592
19 Mindea                         0x147a0dc -[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue] + 4355023068
20 Mindea                         0x1479940 -[APMMeasurement setEnabledOnWorkerQueue:] + 4355021120
21 Mindea                         0x1479858 __29-[APMMeasurement setEnabled:]_block_invoke + 4355020888
22 Mindea                         0x14d1114 __51-[APMScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 4355379476
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
25 libdispatch.dylib              0xb400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
26 libdispatch.dylib              0xbf30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x16cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x16528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4934 _pthread_wqthread + 288
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1590 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4980 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc start_wqthread + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  Mindea                         0x128463c FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 392 (FIRCLSProcess.c:392)
1  Mindea                         0x1284a1c FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 423 (FIRCLSProcess.c:423)
2  Mindea                         0x1292b50 FIRCLSHandler + 34 (FIRCLSHandler.m:34)
3  Mindea                         0x1293354 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 523 (FIRCLSMachException.c:523)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x606c _pthread_start + 136
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10d8 thread_start + 8


DataBaseManager:
@MainActor
final class DataBaseManager: DataBaseManagerProtocol {

// Inits ...

    func fetch<T: PersistentModel>(_ descriptor: FetchDescriptor<T>) async -> Result<[T], DataBaseManagerError> {
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(descriptor)
            try save()
            return .success(result)
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.invalidOperation(error))
        }
    }

    func insert<T: PersistentModel>(_ model: T) async -> Result<Void, DataBaseManagerError> {
        do {
            context.insert(model)
            try save()
            return .success(Void())
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.invalidOperation(error))
        }
    }

    func delete<T: PersistentModel>(model: T.Type) async -> Result<Void, DataBaseManagerError> {
        return deleteModel(model, where: nil)
    }

    func delete<T: PersistentModel>(model: T.Type, where predicate: Predicate<T>) -> Result<Void, DataBaseManagerError> {
        return deleteModel(model, where: predicate)
    }

    func deleteModel<T: PersistentModel>(_ model: T.Type, where predicate: Predicate<T>?) -> Result<Void, DataBaseManagerError> {
        do {
            try context.delete(model: model, where: predicate)
            try save()
            return .success(Void())
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.invalidOperation(error))
        }
    }

    func resetStorage() async -> Result<Void, DataBaseManagerError> {
        do {
            try context.delete(model: AppEventModel.self)
            try context.delete(model: ProfileModel.self)
            return .success(Void())
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.invalidOperation(error))
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private methods

    private func save() throws {
        if context.hasChanges {
            try context.save()
        }
    }
}


Migration Files:
enum MigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [ModelSchemeV1.self, ModelSchemeV2.self, ModelSchemeV3.self, ModelSchemeV3Dot1.self]
    }

    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [migrateV1toV2, migrateV2toV3, migrateV3toV3Dot1]
    }

    static let migrateV1toV2 = MigrationStage.custom(
        fromVersion: ModelSchemeV1.self,
        toVersion: ModelSchemeV2.self,
        willMigrate: nil,
        didMigrate: { context in
            let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<ModelSchemeV1.UserProfileModel>()
            for userProfileModel in try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor) {
                let profileModel = ProfileModel(userProfileModel)
                context.insert(profileModel)
                context.delete(userProfileModel)
            }
            try context.save()
        }
    )
    
    static let migrateV2toV3 = MigrationStage.custom(
        fromVersion: ModelSchemeV2.self,
        toVersion: ModelSchemeV3.self,
        willMigrate: nil,
        didMigrate: nil
    )

    static let migrateV3toV3Dot1 = MigrationStage.custom(
        fromVersion: ModelSchemeV3.self,
        toVersion: ModelSchemeV3Dot1.self,
        willMigrate: nil,
        didMigrate: nil
    )
}


Please include relevant code for where the crash is triggered. The crash seems related to a migration but there’s no such code included for instance.

I've included DataBaseManger and MigrationPlan. However, this crash doesn't seem to be due to migration because model container wouldn't initialize in case of migration issue. In our codebase, ModelContainer initializes and 99% of more than 1000 users don't face such crash.
